# Devise and google oauth. (ror3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise

Is it possible to use devise and google oauth together?
I have successfully setup facebook in devise, but the following
google config doesn't work. Do I have to use oauth2 directly?

```
   config.oauth :google, 'anonymous', 'anonymous',
 :site               => 'https://www.google.com',
 :request_token_path => "/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken",
 :access_token_path  => "/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken",
 :authorize_path     => "/accounts/OAuthGetAuthorizeToken",
 :signature_method   => "RSA-SHA1",
 :private_key_file   => '/rsakey.pem',
 :scope              => "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok my mistake. Google uses oauth whereas devise supports only oauth2 and they are not backwards compatible as far I understand. So I have to use my own implementation.

Comment: can you post your implementation?
I have the exact same problem